# Test program in C to test a cache of a single core micro-processor

Tags: c, caching

I want to write a test program in C which generates the address to access the cache of a single core microprocessor while hitting the corner cases of the cache.

This basically is a cache driver program. The test will run somewhere else. I already know how to write to cache and read from cache. I am not looking for a whole program. If only I can know what address or cases I want to generate I think I will be able to write the program my self. I have read a lot about the cache in few days but I never came across the corner cases or testing of cache sort of subjects. Even if someone can direct me to the source where I can learn it, I will be really grateful for it.

Details of the targeted cache are:

- 32-bit address space
- Word addressed (addresses are left shifted by 2 by adding "00" to end of address inside the processor; this implies that it can address 2A32*4 = 16GBytes of memory)
- Cache is 16KByte in size
- Cache block size (aka cache line size) 16 words (64 bytes = 16*4) 
  number of cache blocks = 256 d
- direct mapped (1-way associative).

From the above information, we can infer that the offset requires 4 bits (2^4 =  16), the index requires 8 bits (2^8 = 256 ) and tag is 20 bits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. OK — the project sounds interesting. Where's the code you need help with? How do you think your user-level code is going to manipulate the cache? Your program doesn't get to control what the CPU (MMU) does — it will work with virtual addresses, but the cache will be holding the data for physical addresses, so you need the virtual-to-physical mapping information (page translation tables, etc) and that information won't be available outside a tiny portion of the kernel of the (as yet unidentified) o/s that you're using.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thank you very much for your quick reply. I came across this question in a code screening test,  They were going to test the code somewhere else. I couldn't even start to code as I did not know how should I test a cache. This is a cache of a single-core microprocessor. The information, given in the question (Which I posted) is all that I have.

Comment: Were you able to get a solution to this problem?